# How can I get the text of an element without children in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, children

How do I get the text of an element without the children?
Neither `element.textContent` nor `element.innerText` seem to be working.

HTML:

```
<body>
<h1>Test Heading</h1>
<div>
Awesome video and music. Thumbs way up. Love it. Happy weekend to you and your family. Love, Sasha
</div>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    fool("body");
</script>
```

and here's the `fool` function:

```
jQuery.fn.justtext = function(text) {
    return $(this).clone()
    .children()
    .remove()
    .end()
    .text();
};

function fool(el) { 

    reverse(el);

    function reverse(el) {
        $(el).children().each(function() {
            if($(this).children().length > 0) {
                reverse(this);
                if($(this).justtext() != "")
                    reverseText(this);
            } else {
               reverseText(this)
            }
        });
    }

    function reverseText(el){
        var text = el.textContent;
        var frag = text.toString().split(/ /);
        var foo = "";
        var punctation_marks = [".",",","?","!"," ",":",";"];
        for(i in frag){
            if(punctation_marks.indexOf(frag[i]) == -1)
                foo += actualReverse(frag[i],punctation_marks) + " ";
        }
        el.textContent = foo;
    }

    function actualReverse(text,punctation_marks) {
        return (punctation_marks.indexOf(text.split("")[text.split("").length-1]) != -1)?text.split("").slice(0,text.split("").length-1).reverse().join("") + text.split("")[text.split("").length-1] : text.split("").reverse().join("");
    }
}
```

**edit**: using `node.nodeType` doesn't really help and here's why:
Imaginge the following HTML

```
<td class="gensmall">
    Last visit was: Sat Mar 31, 2012 10:50 am
    <br>
    <a href="./search.php?search_id=unanswered">View unanswered posts</a> | <a href="./search.php?search_id=active_topics">View active topics</a>
</td>
```

if I'd use `nodeType`, only the text of the `a` element would change , but not the `td` itself ("last visit....")

Comment: Any code? Your selector is probably wrong, `element` does not conain any content when `.textContent` and `innerText` are empty.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by, "without children"?

Comment: @Pointy I only wanna have (as related to the last example - the td cell) the "Last visit was: Sat Mar 31, 2012 10:50 am" without the text from the anchors

Comment: So you want the text content of a node and all its descendant nodes? See the "without children" part made me think that you wanted to *skip* descendants.

Comment: No, I DON'T want the text + descendant but only the text

Comment: Yes but you want the **text** in the descendants, right?

Comment: I want both, the text in the element and in the childrens, but seperated

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just find the text nodes:

```
var element = document.getElementById('whatever'), text = '';
for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; ++i)
  if (element.childNodes[i].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
    text += element.childNodes[i].textContent;
```

*edit* — if you *want* the text in descendant ("children") nodes, and (as is now apparent) you're using jQuery:

```
$.fn.allText = function() {
  var text = '';
  this.each(function() {
    $(this).contents().each(function() {
      if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE)
        text += this.textContent;
      else if (this.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
        text += $(this).allText();
    });
  });
  return text;
};
```

Hold on and I'll test that out :-) (seems to work)

Comment: I suggesst using `Node.TEXT_NODE` instead of "3" as it's more readable.

Comment: might also have to recurse through non-text nodes to find text nodes they contain. (e.g.: table cells)

Comment: @David-SkyMesh: That's exactly my problem. I edited my question

Comment: @Pointy has the answer more or less correct. Write a function called getText() that does what he wrote (the FOR and IF), but add an ELSE case to the IF which calls getText recursively on _elements.childNodes[i]_

Comment: If the elements of the non-text nodes provide structure to the text (e.g: table rows) you may wish to interpret those also (e.g: insert a "\n" in your result text).

Comment: @Pointy: what's there now will work, but only for 1 level deep. It needs to be recursive to work for arbitrary HTML.

Comment: yeah but I DON'T want the text in the descendants. However commenting out `else if (this.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) text += $(this).allText();` works fine for that purpose. Only problem now is, how do I set the text for that specific element? Getting it works, but setting doesn't

Answer (score 7):

The text of an element is also a separate node.
Consider this piece of code:

```
<span>
    Some text
    <span>Inner text</span>
    More text
    <span>More inner text</span>
    Even more text
</span>
```

What do you mean now when you say you want the text of the element?
Just the direct children?

Then this piece of code may help:

```
for (const element of elements) {
    if (element.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This code achieves the same result as the two other answers, but in a more expressive, functional way. The `filter` and `map` array methods are supported in all modern browsers (IE9 and up).

Throwing this in there since the other answers are a bit dated by now.

```
var content = Array.prototype.filter.call(element.childNodes, function (element) {
    return element.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
}).map(function (element) {
    return element.textContent;
}).join("");
```

Comment: Using arrow functions:

`Array.prototype.filter.call(ELEMENT.childNodes, e => e.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE).map(e => e.textContent).join('');`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to answers like Pointy, handling newline character for `<br/>` can be done like this:

```
txt = '';
for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; ++i)
    if (element.childNodes[i].nodeType == 3) {
        txt += element.childNodes[i].textContent;
    } else if (element.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1) {
        name = element.childNodes[i].nodeName || element.childNodes[i].tagName || '';
        if (name.toUpperCase() == 'BR') {
            txt += '\n';
        }
    }
return txt;
```