# How to get the texts without child element texts

Tags: jquery

I want to get the texts in my div but not the texts in child div.

I have

html

```
  <div id='textDiv'>
       texts I want to get
          <span id='textChildDiv'>
             texts I don't want
          </span>
    </div>
```

jquery

```
  $('#textDiv').click(function(){
       alert($(this).text())  //will get 'texts I want to gettexts I don't want'
       //I only want 'texts I want to get' to be returned.
    })
```

I found

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/

for my soulution but it seems there are better approach than his way.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955955/get-text-of-an-element-without-children-in-javascript

Comment: The solution you posted is perfectly valid.

Comment: The link you provided does what you want - what don't you like about it, and what are you looking to improve?

Comment: or this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362085/jquery-get-text-for-element-without-children-text

Comment: @SajjanSarkar He knows about those answers and looking for an alternate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
$('#textDiv').click(function(){

    alert($(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3;
      }).text())
});​
```

As in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jQf6d/

Comment: Since David is the first one reply. I will give him green! thanks for all the helps guys. all +1

Comment: @FlyingCat Well, in fact you can get the exact time of answer by hovering time value which is above author's name and avatar. It should give you the right sequence of answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
var text = $("#textDiv").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).text();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/VcghZ/

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.contents` and fetch the text node alone. See below,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pyaAN/

```
    var result = '';
    $('#textDiv').contents().each(function () {
        if (this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim($(this).text()).length > 0) {
            result += this.nodeValue;
        }
    });
```