# How do I parse ill-structued html code?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html code that I'd like to parse (some elements are stripped to enhance readability):

```
</div>
            <article class="article-detail-description">
                <h1 class="page-heading">
                    Postulat operacyjności definicji w naukach społecznych
                    <br /><small>Definition’s Operativeness Postulate in Social Sciences</small>
                </h1>

                <div>
                    <strong>Author(s): </strong>Jakub Karpiński<br /><strong>Subject(s): </strong>Social Sciences<br /><strong>Published by: </strong>Instytut Filozofii i Socjologii Polskiej Akademii Nauk<br/><strong>Keywords: </strong>operationism; definition of property; definition of indicator;  concepts selection
<br/>
                </div>
                  <p class="summary"><strong>Summary/Abstract: </strong> 
The article’s primary goal is to demonstrate the problems inherited in “operationism – antioperationism” polemics.
</p>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active" ><a href="#details" data-toggle="tab">Details</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#tableOfContents" data-toggle="tab">Contents</a></li>

                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="details">
                        <p class="journal-link"><strong>Journal: </strong><a href="/search/journal-detail?id=10">Studia Socjologiczne</a></p>   
                        <ul class="article-additional-info">
                            <li><strong>Issue Year:</strong> 2011</li><li><strong>Issue No:</strong> 1 (200)</li><li><strong>Page Range:</strong> 65-80</li><li><strong>Page Count:</strong> 15</li><li><strong>Language:</strong> Polish</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

I can read all of it by using

`document.getElementsByClassName("article-detail-description")[0].textContent`.

To read only `<p class="summary"` I use:

`getElementsByClassName("summary")[0].textContent`

However, the latter is imperfect because it shows also `Summary/Abstract:`)

I am interested in many elements, let's take the following as examples:

**1**. Postulat operacyjności definicji w naukach społecznych

I can get:

```
Postulat operacyjności definicji w naukach społecznych
Definition’s Operativeness Postulate in Social Sciences
```

To get it I use: `document.getElementsByClassName("page-heading")[0].innerText`

How do I get separately `Postulat operacyjności definicji w naukach społecznych` and `Definition’s Operativeness Postulate in Social Sciences`?

**2**. I'd like to get e.g. `2011` from:

```
`<li><strong>Issue Year:</strong> 2011</li><li>`
```

This time I have no clue whatsoever as to getting this information. The same is true for `Issue No:` and others.

Comment: You aren't parsing anything, you're reading properties of DOM elements.

Comment: There's also nothing "ill structured" about what you describe. HTML nodes can have sub nodes as well as sub text. That does not make it badly formatted or unstructured.

Comment: Possible solution is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955955/get-text-of-an-element-without-children-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether the structure is stable; but you can go access text nodes:

```js
var heading = document.getElementsByClassName('page-heading')[0];
var polish = heading.childNodes[0].textContent.trim();
var english = heading.childNodes[2].textContent.trim();
console.log("Polish:", polish);
console.log("English:", english);

var li = document.querySelector('.article-additional-info li');
var issueYear = li.childNodes[1].textContent.trim();
console.log("Issue Year:", issueYear);
```

```html
</div>
            <article class="article-detail-description">
                <h1 class="page-heading">
                    Postulat operacyjności definicji w naukach społecznych
                    <br /><small>Definition’s Operativeness Postulate in Social Sciences</small>
                </h1>

                <div>
                    <strong>Author(s): </strong>Jakub Karpiński<br /><strong>Subject(s): </strong>Social Sciences<br /><strong>Published by: </strong>Instytut Filozofii i Socjologii Polskiej Akademii Nauk<br/><strong>Keywords: </strong>operationism; definition of property; definition of indicator;  concepts selection
<br/>
                </div>
                  <p class="summary"><strong>Summary/Abstract: </strong> 
The article’s primary goal is to demonstrate the problems inherited in “operationism – antioperationism” polemics.
</p>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active" ><a href="#details" data-toggle="tab">Details</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#tableOfContents" data-toggle="tab">Contents</a></li>

                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="details">
                        <p class="journal-link"><strong>Journal: </strong><a href="/search/journal-detail?id=10">Studia Socjologiczne</a></p>   
                        <ul class="article-additional-info">
                            <li><strong>Issue Year:</strong> 2011</li><li><strong>Issue No:</strong> 1 (200)</li><li><strong>Page Range:</strong> 65-80</li><li><strong>Page Count:</strong> 15</li><li><strong>Language:</strong> Polish</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```