# identify a specific .html tag AFTER the DOM has loaded

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Below is the HTML structure that I am working with:

[image]

I am trying to identify a specific tag **after** the DOM has loaded. I am gathering all `h1` tags into an array, then looping through all of those tags and searching their text content for the specific text content in the HTML. However, the line `console.log("identified");` is never executed.  Where am I going wrong here?

```
var h1Tags = document.getElementsByTagName("H1");
var h1Text = "Settings: ";
for (var i = 0; i < h1Tags.length; i++) {
  if (h1Tags[i].textContent === h1Text) {
    console.log("identified");                    
  }
}
```

Comment: The `.textContent` includes **all** the text, including text in that `<span>`.

Comment: I don't recall checking this before, but you may wish to try... You are looking without success for "H1". Can you try looking for "h1"? Just a guess...

Comment: Before you ask: [get text of an element without children in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9955955/215552), or just do `h1Tags[i].textContent.includes(h1Text)` as your condition.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - that did it.  Thank you!