# How to get a copy of text inside a div which is not wrapped inside any HTML tag?

Tags: html, dom

I am trying to grab the text inside a div container and perform some logic based upon the text content instead of changing it. I tried to use `Node.childNodes` but it returns a live Nodelist instead of a copy.

Here is the DOM structure, I am trying to grab `text without a container` from it only.

```
<div class="container" >
    <span >text inside span</span> 
      text without a container
     <button>text inside button new</button>
     <button>text inside button</button>
  </div>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

**Desired Output**:

'text without a container' as a string

Comment: Which is your code? try to use `<>` for create a complete snippet. can you write the desired output?

Comment: Did you do anything with your node list? like loop over it and try something like a .text() ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get text of an element without children in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955955/get-text-of-an-element-without-children-in-javascript)

Comment: @HereticMonkey No, I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I am not sure if my code would help understanding the issue,  I have updated the question to include desired output.

Comment: Look at the first code block of the accepted answer; there is no jQuery there.

Comment: @Culyx I did this Node.childNodes[1].toString() but it didn't work.

Comment: @HereticMonkey

Yeah, that may work but it looks like many lines of codes for a trivial task like this, it may be necessary 8 years ago but I am hoping it could be solved easily with fewer lines of code using newer APIs.

Comment: There aren't any newer APIs. The answer you've gotten is the same as [this answer from that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9956031/215552).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');

const nodes = parent.childNodes;

let text = "";

for (let node of nodes) {
  if (node.nodeName === '#text') {
    text += node.textContent.trim();
  }
}

console.log('Final result: ', text);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <span>Inside span</span> 
  I'm free! as a bird!
  <span>I wish I was</span>
</div>
```

This will loop through all of the child nodes and will only extract text that is not within another element.