# How can you get an element's text content without getting its children's text content?

Tags: javascript, playwright

Let's say you are using Playwright to validate some HTML that looks like this:

```html
<span>
  The time is:
  <time>5:30 pm</time>
</span>
```

You can use this code:

```js
page.locator('span', {has: page.locator('time')}).textContent();
```

to get:

> The time is: 5:30 pm

But what if you *just* want the first part, since it won't change?

> The time is:

Is there any way to get an element's text content without getting its children's text?

Currently the only solution I can come up with is get the text of both and then remove the child's text:

```js
const parent = page.locator('span', {has: page.locator('time')});
const parentText = parent.textContent();
const child = parent.locator('time');
const childText = child.textContent();
const onlyParentText = parentText(0, parentText.length - childText.length);
```

...but that's a lot of JavaScript just to get a single DOM node's text.

Is there any easier way to do the above using Playwright features?

Comment: If you're going to assert on it and don't want the specific time to mess up your expectation, just use e.g. `/^The time is:/` or similar (or, better, have more control of what's rendered).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the text of an element without children in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955955/how-can-i-get-the-text-of-an-element-without-children-in-javascript)

Comment: @HereticMonkey As it turns out, Playwright at the present time probably has to fall back on similar code from that question, but it's not really a duplicate because this question asks about Playwright. It's conceivable (albeit unlikely) that Playwright introduces a feature to its API that does this, or that there's some other Playwright-specific approach to extracting text nodes. Since OP isn't using `.evaluate()`, that's part of the answer, so there's still a leap to make between where OP is at and the suggested dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Playwright has this built-in, so going into `evaluate` is probably the best approach:

```js
const text = await page
  .locator("span", {has: page.locator("time")})
  .evaluate(el => el.firstChild.textContent);
```

To generalize it to cases with multiple text nodes or arbitrary positioning within a parent,

```js
const text = await page
  .locator("span", {has: page.locator("time")})
  .evaluate(el =>
    [...el.childNodes]
      .filter(e => e.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
      .map(e => e.textContent)
  );
```

Expect to trim and join text as necessary. For example:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.39.0

const html = `
<p>
  a <b>ignore this</b>
</p>
<p> b <b>ignore this</b> c </p>
<p> d <b>ignore this</b> e </p>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.firefox.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const text = await page
    .locator("p")
    .evaluateAll(els =>
      els.map(el =>
        [...el.childNodes]
          .filter(
            e =>
              e.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE &&
              e.textContent.trim()
          )
          .map(e => e.textContent.trim())
      )
    );
  console.log(text); // => [ [ 'a' ], [ 'b', 'c' ], [ 'd', 'e' ] ]
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77767583/how-can-you-get-an-elements-text-content-without-getting-its-childrens-text-co/77767612#comment137102216_77767583), if you're asserting in a test, probably best to use

```js
await expect(locator).toHaveText(/^\s*The time is:/m);
```